# Relation between irreducible mod $p$ and irreducible mod $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have often seen the statement that a monic $f(x)\in \mathbf{Z}[x]$ is irreducible in $\mathbf{Q}[x]$ if we can show that there is a prime $p$ such that $\bar{f}(x)$ is irreducible in $(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z})[x]$. But the proof of the statement seems to work for any integer $n$, not just for a prime $p$. Is there a reason why we are usually only concerned with the case of mod $p$?

Comment: Could you mention the steps of the proof you know?

Comment: Beware: the answer you accepted is not correct - see my comment there.

Comment: The exact statement you refer to is: if $f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]$, and there exists a prime $p$ _not dividing the leading coefficient of $f$_ for which $\bar f(x)$ is irreducible in $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)[x]$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[x]$. It's possible that the proof generalizes with $n$ in place of $p$, with the condition being that the leading coefficient of $f$ is relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: What about the case where $f(x)=2x$? It is irreducible in $(\mathbf{Z}/3\mathbf{Z})[x]$ as $2$ becomes a unit, but is reducible in $\mathbf{Z}[x]$ into $f(x)=(2)(x)$.

Comment: anything unclear in my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The ring homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb{Z}[x]\to \Bbb{Z}/(n)[x]$ restricts to the multiplicative monoid homomorphism
$\phi:\Bbb{Z}[x]_{monic}\to \Bbb{Z}/(n)[x]_{monic}$

> Gauss lemma : if $f\in \Bbb{Z}[x]_{monic}$ is not irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ then $f=gh\in \Bbb{Z}[x]_{monic}$

Thus $\phi(f)=\phi(g)\phi(h)\in \Bbb{Z}/(n)[x]_{monic}$.

> Conversely if no such factorization of $\phi(f)$ exists then $f$ is irreducible.

When $n=p$ then $\Bbb{Z}/(p)[x]$ is an integral domain.

But when $n$ is not prime then we have $(1+2x)^2=1\in \Bbb{Z}/(4)[x]$ and $\,x = (2x+3)(3x+2)\in \Bbb{Z}/(6)[x]$ so we need to restrict to  $\overline{g},\overline{h}$ in the monoid with cancellation $\Bbb{Z}/(n)[x]_{monic}$, to get a meaningful definition of irreducibility $\bmod n$.

Comment: There is no standard definition of irreducible, associate etc in rings with zero-divisors, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/208080/242) for some literature links on the various notions in use.

Comment: @Gone Is your comment addressed to me ? The point of my answer is to give the meaningful definition of irreducibility in $Z/(n)[x]_{monic}$ in the context of lifting to irreducibility in $\Bbb{Z}[x]_{monic}$. Is it unclear to you why it is so ?

Comment: At reuns: The comment was not specifically addressed to you, and likely will be helpful to many readers since this is a little-known topic to most readers of this site. There is nothing unclear to me here.