# Doubt about degrees of a polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was reading a statement related to the ring of polynomials defined over an arbitrary ring $A$ and found that given polynomials $a(x),b(x) \in A[x]$ such that $a(x) \cdot b (x) \neq 0$ the following is true: $$\text{dg}(a(x) \cdot b(x)) \leq \text{dg}(a(x))+\text{dg}(b(x))$$
If $A$ does not have divisors of zero then equality is satisfied in the previous relation.
I could easily verify that equality occurs over fields, since every field is an integral domain and therefore will not have zero divisors. The problem is that I have not been able to find or construct a simple example that allows me to realize that inequality can occur.

Comment: The term in English is "integral domain", not "integrity domain".

Comment: Thank you very much, I have some problems speaking and writing in English. My native language is Spanish.

Comment: Nontrivial examples are in many prior posts, e.g. $\,x = (3+2x)(2-3x)\in \Bbb Z_6[x]\,$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/208080/242).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=2x$ and $g(x)=3x$ over the ring $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$.

$fg(x)=f(x)g(x)=6x^2=0$. Thus $fg$ has degree $-\infty$, whereas $\deg(f)=\deg(g)=1$.

Hence, inequality occurs.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: $0$ does not usually have degree zero (it messes up the formula for degree of a product in a field, makes the condition for equality false). It either has no degree, or is assigned "$-\infty$". It is the lack of degree for the zero polynomial which is the reason Euclidean functions are not required to be defined at $0$.

Comment: To avoid that issue you can take $g(x)=3x+1$, and the product has degree $1$.

Comment: I have fixed the mistake mentioned by Arturo.

Answer (score 2):

Take *any* ring $A$ with a non-zero zero divisor, so $a \cdot b = 0$ for some $a,b \in A \setminus \{0\}$. These are non-zero constant polynomials, hence of degree $0$, but their product is $0$, which has degree $-\infty$.

If you want to exclude the zero polynomial here: $a \cdot (bX+1) =a$ has degree $0$.